# MySQL finding result in query1 in result of query2

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a table itinerary where all itineraries are saved. Then, I'm fetching all those data inside the itinerary table into an array of checkbox depending on `$_SESSION` value.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require("aacfs.php");
echo"<div class='box' style='display:inline-block;' >
<table width='800'><tr><td>
  <table width=100 align=left class='hovertable' style='display:inline-block;'><tr><th align=center bgcolor=silver><font face=consolas>Choose Itinerary</font></th></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></br>
      <form method=post>"; 


$result=mysql_query("select * from itinerary where aircraft = '$_SESSION[rtyp]' group by location");
    $y=mysql_affected_rows();
    for($i=0;$i<$y;$i++)
    {$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $pr=$row['icode'];
        $n=$row['location'];
        $l=$row['btime'];
echo"<table border=1 align=center width=250>
          <tr><td width=15>
          <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l'>
          </td><td>$n</td><td width=5>$l</td></tr>
          </table>";

        }
?>
```

And then, I have another table where a previously selected itineraries are saved. Let's call it location table. I want to select all the data there then, find it in the previous query I fetch. If found, that checkbox will be automatically be checked.

So for example I have these data from the itinerary table:

[image]

and then I have these data from the location table:

[image]

The value from the location table should be *checked*. Meaning the `Cebu - Bohol` and `Bohol - Cebu` value on the array of checkbox should be *checked*. I just don't know how to do it using the queries. Please help me. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I'm able to do what I want using this code,

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from itinerary where aircraft = '$_SESSION[rtyp]' group by location");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $pr=$row['icode'];
        $n=$row['location'];
        $l=$row['btime'];
        $res=mysql_query("select * from location where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $loc=$row1['location'];
            if($n==$loc)
            {
                echo"<table border=1 align=center width=250>
                <tr><td width=15>
                <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l' checked='yes'>
                </td><td>$n</td><td width=5>$l</td></tr>
                </table>";

                $t=$_POST['prod'];
            }
        elseif($n!=$loc)
        {
            echo"<table border=1 align=center width=250>
            <tr><td width=15>
            <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l'>
            </td><td>$n</td><td width=5>$l</td></tr>
            </table>";

            $t=$_POST['prod'];
        }
    }
    }
```

but,

[image]

as you can see, it echoes the itineraries twice. How can I echo the itineraries just once? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved it using this code:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from itinerary where aircraft = '$_SESSION[rtyp]' group by location");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $pr=$row['icode'];
        $n=$row['location'];
        $l=$row['btime'];
        $res=mysql_query("select * from location where reservno = '$_SESSION[rno]'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $loc=$row1['location'];
                if($n==$loc){$ctr="true"; break;}
                else{$ctr="false";}

        }
        if($ctr=="true"){
                echo"<table border=1 align=center width=250>
                <tr><td width=15>
                <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l' checked='yes'>
                </td><td>$n</td><td width=5>$l</td></tr>
                </table>";

                $t=$_POST['prod'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo"<table border=1 align=center width=250>
                <tr><td width=15>
                <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l'>
                </td><td>$n</td><td width=5>$l</td></tr>
                </table>";

                $t=$_POST['prod'];
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.*, l.location is not null as selected
from
    itinerary i
    left join
    location l on i.location = l.location
where aircraft = '$_SESSION[rtyp]'
group by location
```

Now check if selected is true in the PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the `icode` doesn't exist in the location table. I'm comparing them using the `location` (e.g `Cebu - Bohol`). The `location` field is unique.

Comment: @xjshiya Ok just changed the comparison to `location`

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't do what I want. Is there something like `if query_result_location exist in query_result_itinerary then <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l' checked='yes'>`, `if doesn't exist then <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l'>`? I'm hoping for some help in the PHP part as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Inner Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Giving a shot:

```
SELECT a.location, a.btime FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.location = b.location
```

By the way, where's Baguio?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried it but it doesn't do what I want. Is there something like `if query_result_location exist in query_result_itinerary then <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l' checked='yes'>`, `if doesn't exist then <input type='checkbox' value='$n -> $l'>`? I'm hoping for some help in the PHP part as well. And I'm going to add Baguio as well. :)